# Setting sdkconfig using platform.io for the ESP32

Tags: esp32, platformio

I was wondering if anybody managed to set the SDKConfig.h file for the ESP32 when using platform.io to upload code, and if so how it is done.

Thanks in advance!

✌️

Answer (score 0):

You can copy and modify the file **SDKConfig.h** into your project **include** folder from:

```
/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/config/

or paste "CONFIG_ULP_COPROC_RESERVE_MEM" in your code and <Ctrl+LClick> to go to this file in your system.
```

And add this to your **platformio.ini** so that the file in your project has priority

```
build_flags = 
  -Iinclude
```

Tested with framework-arduinoespressif32 Version 3.10006.210326 (1.0.6)

Let me know if it works for you, I'm guessing it could work with the other frameworks?

if some of the definitions gives you a problem because they are defined elsewhere just add a guard like this:

```
#ifndef CONFIG_FLASHMODE_DIO
#define CONFIG_FLASHMODE_DIO 1
#endif
```